# Chaquopy: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'

Tags: android-studio, chaquopy

I am trying to make an app with android studio, i imported `chaquopy` and python runs it.. (app is ok fine but when start python script `cv2` is missing)
in the python program I use `opencv` so I have to import the library the fact is that if I add:

```
     python {      
         pip {   
              install "opencv-python"  
            }
        }
```

in the `defaultconfig` and try sync now:

```
*** 
Process 'command 'python3.8'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
***
***
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugPythonRequirements'.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
***
***
> Process 'command 'python3.8'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
***
***
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
***
***
Process 'command '/usr/bin/python3.8'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
***
gradle is update at last version
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad I just need sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils
now work

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the `python3-distutils` or `python3.8-distutils` package.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239829, which is the first Google result for this error message.

Comment: that was the first thing i did but no same mistake. I think it's pip in the default config because it doesn't even compile the gradle to me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by installing python 3.8

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install python3.8
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

Check which python version it is pointing out to:

```
python3 --version
```

If it is still not python 3.8, switch to 3.8 by running the below command and choosing python 3.8

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```